# How to change a file's permissions/attributes to make it not readable in Windows with Python

Tags: python, windows, permissions, attributes

I am trying to test some code, and to test it I need to get an exception in a specific location:

```
def makeThisFunctionReturnTrue(filename):
    if os.path.exists(input) and os.path.isfile(filename):
        try: 
            open(filename, "r")
        except IOError, err:
            return True
    return False
```

I need to figure out what input filename would cause the above function to return True. I think that the solution lies with either changing permissions or attributes in the file. I am able to force the error manually by going into the properties of a file through windows explorer and then going to security and then denying permissions. However, I need to be able to create the file dynamically in Python and then change the permissions through Python to force the error.

My first thought was to use os.chmod(); however, this function appears to be limited in a Windows environment.

A co-worker of mine suggested that I use win32file.SetFileAttributes(), but I cannot find any good documentation on this function.

Thanks for the help.

Caleb Rouleau

Comment: I'm guessing you're not happy with just returning true without trying to open the file to integration test the rest of your application?

Comment: The `win32file` functions are more or less straight bindings to the Win32 API. Try the documentation for that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365535(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you. I am looking into this now.

Comment: I couldn't figure it out from that documentation. I did find someone who did it in C# though: http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/4659-Programmatically-deny-e-Read-permission-fil.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just raise the exception yourself

```
raise IOError('SUITABLE INFO HERE')
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is after, seeing as he explicitly asked for a programmatic way to make a file unreadable.

Comment: @millimoose quoting the OP - "To test it I need to get an exception in a specific location" - forcefully raising the exception is much better than mucking about with the filesystem IMHO. And if Python can create the file, it's almost a given, you won't get an exception because it's successful.

Comment: I am trying to test a module from outside of it. I cannot change the code I am testing because that would defeat the purpose. The only way to test a particular sequence of code is to generate an IOError. The only way I can see to generate an IOError without changing the code that generates it is to give it a file without read permissions.

Comment: @CalebRouleau I'm not sure if you're in agreement with me, or if you're pondering something else; would you be so kind to clarify?

Comment: millimoose is exactly correct. I cannot do it the way you're talking about.

Comment: Okay. Forgive me for my ignorance, but was is the difference between attempting to open a file and getting an IOError and mocking you've opened a file and forcing an IOError - the code branch and unittests/whatever are still the same... In testing you often need to "force" an error because the situation is unlikely but could possibly happen at runtime etc...

Comment: The difference is that simply raising an error myself requires changing the code that I am testing.